# Create fish shell prevd keybinding which doesn't require carriage return and doesn't display warning

Tags: fish

I'm trying to bind Ctrl-minus to prevd in fish. The desired behaviour is that I press the keybinding and I go to the previous directory. I have tried this:

```
bind \c_  'prevd'
```

The problem is that I have to press enter after pressing the keybinding for it to work. Also it displays the message 'Hit end of history…' when I hit the end of history. I would like to suppress this. Does anyone know how I could achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I have to press enter after pressing the keybinding for it to work

You actually don't. The `prevd` happens immediately, but the prompt isn't repainted, so it doesn't display the new directory.

So the binding needs to also do `commandline -f repaint`.

> Also it displays the message 'Hit end of history…' when I hit the end of history.

That message is printed by `prevd`, on stdout (for some reason). To inhibit stdout, redirect it to /dev/null, like `prevd >/dev/null`.

So, in conclusion:

```
bind \c_ 'prevd >/dev/null; commandline -f repaint'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a lot of trouble just to return to the previous directory. My recommendation is to create an abbreviation:

```
abbr -a -g -- - 'cd -'
```

With that you just type `-` followed by `[enter]`.